# Instanciate ViewModel from Fragment with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to create a instance of a ViewModel using Android Architecture Components in my Fragment with Kotlin and I obtain the next error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: campanoon.cronometrohiit, PID: 3871
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class campanoon.cronometrohiit.RoutinesViewModel 
at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:153)
```

My ViewModel:

```
class RoutinesViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
private val routineDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application).routineDao()

fun generateSimpleList() : List<Routine> {
    routineDao.insertRoutine(Routine(null,"Prueba 1", "00:10","00:30","30:00",3))
    routineDao.insertRoutine(Routine(null,"Prueba 2", "00:15","00:30","15:00",2))
    routineDao.insertRoutine(Routine(null,"Prueba 3", "00:20","00:30","20:00",5))

    return routineDao.getRoutines()

}

}
```

My fragment:

```
class RoutinesFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var routinesViewModel : RoutinesViewModel


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val v : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_routines, container, false)
    routinesViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RoutinesViewModel::class.java)

    return v
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass in parameter in to constructor of `ViewModel` you'll need to use  `ViewModel.Factory`

```
open class RoutinesViewModelFactory(private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
     override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(RoutinesViewModel::class.java)) {
            return RoutinesViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

If you're using dagger for example you'd inject instance of `RoutinesViewModelFactory` in your fragment

```
@Inject lateinit var routinesViewModelFactory: RoutinesViewModelFactory
```

and then retrieve `ViewModel` instance by calling

```
routinesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, RoutinesViewModelFactory).get(RoutinesViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: I've tried but I get the following error:     kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property routinesViewModelFactory has not been initialized

Comment: That was as an example if you were using Dagger....which sounds like you're not using?  If not, then use whatever DI framework you're using to inject instance of this or at least as test for now create an instance of `RoutinesViewModelFactory` in your fragment (passing `application` in constructor)

Comment: No, because I am junior in android development and had not done dependency injections. Thanks for your response, you've helped me.

Comment: np....but you can also do this without dependency injection...as mentioned you can  if needed just create instance of `RoutinesViewModelFactory` directly (or though your own service locator/factory etc)